# How to implement scrolling bottom down when we got to the beginning of the content, inside the scrollview using pure SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, bottom-sheet

Here is my attempt to implement this functionality, I also tried to solve it through UIKit, it worked, but I ran into problems with dynamically changing the content of SwiftUI, which was inside UIScrollView. More precisely, the problem was in changing the height of the container

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B92j5.jpg

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 300
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { _ in
                    Color.red
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 125, alignment: .center)
                }
                .overlay(
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        let offset = proxy.frame(in: .named("scroll")).minY
                        Color.clear.preference(key: ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: offset)
                            .frame(width: 0, height: 0, alignment: .center)
                    })
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
            .onPreferenceChange(ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                if value >= 0 {
                    offset = value + 300
                }
            }
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                print("scrooll")
                print(value)
            })
                     
                     
                     )
        }
        .offset(y: offset)
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 25, coordinateSpace: .local)
                    .onChanged({ value in
            offset = value.translation.height + 300
        }))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the behavior you want to achieve?

Comment: @ChrisR When I do a pulldown, I want the move gesture to work, not the scrollview gesture

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how you can lock the `ScrollView` when you are at the top, and then allow the `DragGesture` to operate instead of scroll. I removed your `PreferenceKey` as it was not necessary. I also used frame reader to determine where in the scroll view the top cell was. Code is extensively commented.

```
struct ScrollViewWithPulldown: View {
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 300
    @State private var scrollEnabled = true
    @State private var cellRect: CGRect = .zero
    
    // if the top of the cell is in view, origin.y will be greater than or equal to zero
    var topInView: Bool {
        cellRect.origin.y >= 0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { id in
                    Color.red
                        .id(id)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 125, alignment: .center)
                        // This is inspired by https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-share-layout-information/
                        .copyFrame(in: .named("scroll"), to: $cellRect)
                        .onChange(of: cellRect) { _ in
                            if id == 0 { // insure the first view however you need to
                                if topInView {
                                    scrollEnabled = false
                                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                                        scrollEnabled = true
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    scrollEnabled = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .disabled(!scrollEnabled)
            .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
        }
        .offset(y: offset)
        .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ value in
            // Scrolling down
            if value.translation.height > 0 && topInView {
                scrollEnabled = false
                print("scroll locked")
                print(value)
            } else { // Scrolling up
                scrollEnabled = true
                print("scroll up")
                print(value)
            }
            
        })
                    .onEnded({ _ in
            scrollEnabled = true
        })
        )
        
    }
}
```

A view extension inspired by [FiveStar Blog](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-share-layout-information/):

```
extension View {
    func readFrame(in space: CoordinateSpace, onChange: @escaping (CGRect) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: FrameInPreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.frame(in: space))
            }
        )
            .onPreferenceChange(FrameInPreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
    }
    
    func copyFrame(in space: CoordinateSpace, to binding: Binding<CGRect>) -> some View {
        self.readFrame(in: space) { frame in
            binding.wrappedValue = frame
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately, I don’t need exactly what you got, I tried to write a similar code, but the problem is that I need DragGestore to work immediately after blocking the scrollviews without lifting your finger from the screen, about the same implementation is done by the native modal view